# Error verifying message using Crypto++ on iOS

Tags: ios, security, rsa, public-key, crypto++

## Problem

I am trying to verify a given message with its signature and public key. It works fine using the iOS provided Security Framework, but I cannot manage to make it work using the Crypto++ library (must use).

I followed the same steps using the CryptoPP Library and verified everything 10 times, rewrote some parts differently, but it still throws the same exception:

> "PK_Signer: key too short for this signature scheme"

## context

#### Data worked with

- I receive a JWT (Json Web Token) with a header, payload and signature.
- I retrieve the service's base64 encoded X509 certificate (which includes the public key).

#### Steps followed for verification

1. **Certificate**

   1. Base64 decode the certificate
   2. Extract the public key from certificate
2. **Signature (third segment of a JWB)**

   1. Pad the signature to a multiple of 4 with some "="
   2. URLBase64 decode it
3. **Message to verify**

   1. Message = (JSW Header) + "." + (JWT Payload). This is already done in the code, message is argument named "headerAndPayload.
4. **Verify SHA256 bytes with PKCS1, RSA**

   1. SHA256 digest of the Message
   2. Verification using:

      1. Public Key
      2. SHA256 Digest of the message
      3. Signature

### iOS Working Code

(Only parts that matter, as verification works fine on iOS)

- **Certificate**

  1. `NSData *certificateData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:certificateString options:0];`
  2. `SecKeyRef getPublicKeyFromCertificate(certificateData)` found online, works fine.
- **Verify SHA256 bytes with PKCS1, RSA**

  ```
  BOOL PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA(NSData* message, NSData* signature, SecKeyRef publicKey)
  {
      size_t signedHashBytesSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
      const void* signedHashBytes = [signature bytes];

      size_t hashBytesSize = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
      void* hashBytes = malloc(hashBytesSize);
      if (!CC_SHA256([message bytes], (CC_LONG)[message length], hashBytes)) {
          return NULL;
      }

      OSStatus status = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                                    kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256,
                                    hashBytes,
                                    hashBytesSize,
                                    signedHashBytes,
                                    signedHashBytesSize);

      return status == errSecSuccess;
  }
  ```

### Code using CryptoPP Library (working with same set of data)

I copy/paste the whole code with numbers corresponding to the description and some additional comments, like size of structures returned.

```
+(bool)verifyBase64EncodedCertificate:(NSString *)certificateString
         base64URLEncodedJWTSignature:(NSString *)urlEncodedSignature
                              message:(NSString *)headerAndPayload
{
    // 1. Certificate
    // 1.1 Decode the certificate
    std::string base64EncodedCertificate = certificateString.UTF8String;
    std::string decodedCertificate;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(base64EncodedCertificate,
                              true,
                              new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(decodedCertificate))
                              );

    // 1.2 Extract Public Key from certificate
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue certificateByteQueue, publicKeyByteQueue;
    certificateByteQueue.Put((byte *)&decodedCertificate[0], decodedCertificate.size());
    certificateByteQueue.MessageEnd();
    try
    {
        GetPublicKeyFromCert(certificateByteQueue, publicKeyByteQueue);
        // This method comes from CryptoPP docs so I assume it works... certificate gets checked again later on.
    }
    catch(std::exception &)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to extract the public key from the CA certificate." << std::endl;
        return nil;
    }
    //publicKeyByteQueue.CurrentSize() = 294


    // 2. Decode Signature
    std::string base64URLEncodedSignature = urlEncodedSignature.UTF8String;
    unsigned long paddingForURLEncodedSignature = 4 - (base64URLEncodedSignature.length() % 4);
    base64URLEncodedSignature.insert(base64URLEncodedSignature.begin(), paddingForURLEncodedSignature, '=');
    std::string decodedSignature;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss1(base64URLEncodedSignature,
                               true,
                               new CryptoPP::Base64URLDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(decodedSignature))
                               );
    const byte *decodedSignaturePointer = (byte *)&decodedSignature[0];
    size_t decodedSignatureSize = decodedSignature.size();

    // Certificate Signature as Byte Block
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock certSignature;
    certSignature.Assign(decodedSignaturePointer, decodedSignatureSize);

    // decodedSignatureSize = 256
    // certSignature.size() = 256


    // 3. Message to verify (available already concatenated)
    std::string message = headerAndPayload.UTF8String;
    const byte *messagePointer = (const byte *)message.c_str();
    const size_t messageLength = message.length();        
    // MessageLength = 693

    // 4.1 hash message using SHA256
    byte digest [CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];
    CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(digest, messagePointer, messageLength);

    // 4.2  Create Verifier assigned public key and test
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PKCS1v15, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Verifier verifier;
    verifier.AccessKey().Load(publicKeyByteQueue);
    if (!verifier.AccessKey().Validate(prng, 3))
    {
        throw CryptoPP::Exception(CryptoPP::Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Failed to validate public key");
    }        

    // verifier.SignatureLength() = 256 = certSignature.size()
    if(certSignature.size() != verifier.SignatureLength())
    {
        std::cerr << "The signature size is does not match the algorithm used for signing." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // 4. Actual Verification (1st way of doing it)
    CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter vf(verifier);
    try
    {
        vf.Put(digest, CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);
        vf.Put(certSignature, certSignature.size());
        vf.MessageEnd(); // Throws exception here PK_Signer: key too short for this signature scheme
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught an exception while verifying the signature:" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "\t" << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(vf.GetLastResult())
    {
        std::cout << "The signature verified." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Signature verification failed." << std::endl;
    }
    return 1;


    // 4. Actual Verification (2d way of doing it)
    bool verified = verifier.VerifyMessage(digest,                  CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE,
                                           decodedSignaturePointer, decodedSignatureSize);
    // Also throw same exception PK_Signer: key too short for this signature scheme

    return verified;
```

The only difference I can see between the pure iOS code and the CryptoPP code is during the verification process, the iOS method takes an additional argument *kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256*

```
SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256,
                ...)
```

But otherwise I feel like I have replicated exactly the same concepts using the CryptoPP library.

Any help is very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> vf.Put(digest, CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);

The signature is *not* the hash size. The signature is the size of the modulus (or more correctly, ***`[0,n-1]`***). After protocol framing, the signature may be larger than the modulus size. Also see [What is the length of an RSA signature?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3505) on the Cryptography Stack Exchange.

As for creating an equivalent iOS example, using the "Raw Sign" or "Raw Encrypt", see [Raw RSA](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA) on the Crypto++ wiki. Its usually a bad idea for you to do the low level things like a modular exponentiation. You should try to stay in the protocols and cryptosystems, like `RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer` and `RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Verifier`.

Also checkout the [`RSASS` class](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/annotated.html), which is RSA Signature Scheme. I'm guessing you will probably want a `RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA256>::Signer` and `RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA256>::Verifier`:

```
$ grep -IR Signer * | grep typedef
luc.h:typedef LUCSS<PKCS1v15, SHA>::Signer LUCSSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer;
pubkey.h:   typedef PK_FinalTemplate<TF_SignerImpl<SchemeOptions> > Signer;
pubkey.h:   typedef PK_FinalTemplate<DL_SignerImpl<SchemeOptions> > Signer;
rsa.h:typedef RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA>::Signer RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer;
rsa.h:typedef RSASS<PKCS1v15, Weak1::MD2>::Signer RSASSA_PKCS1v15_MD2_Signer;
rsa.h:typedef RSASS<PKCS1v15, Weak1::MD5>::Signer RSASSA_PKCS1v15_MD5_Signer;
```

Comment: There is something I don't understand. When I call the verify method, is the "message" the hash of the message or the message itself? Either way, I've tried both and I always have the "Public Key too Short" error. Thanks

Comment: *"When I call the verify method, is the "message" the hash of the message or the message itself..."* - For a ***Signature Scheme with Appendix (SSA)***, it is the original message that was signed. For a ***Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery (PSSR)***, the message is recovered from the signature.

Comment: @jww - I also get this error on ARM64 (device ) build.. With the same resources code then I build for ARM7 (device), i386 and x86_64 (Terminal Version), its working find.. Any reason of this ? ... im using RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA256>::Signer and RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA256>::Verifier for verifying

Comment: @jww the weird is... if im running on terminal on my 64 bit mac is working fine but not in my ios device arm64